# Set `platformVersion` for AWS Fargate when deploying a Kubernetes Deployment config file

Tags: kubernetes, aws-fargate, amazon-eks, kubernetes-deployment

I am attempting to deploy a stateful Kubernetes service via a Deployment config file that requires the use of an EFS mount.

The issue I'm having is that this is only supported on Fargate `v1.4.0` and by default `LATEST` is set to `v1.3.0`.

Is there a way for me to inform my EKS Fargate profile that this deployment requires the newer platform version?

Answer (score 0):

I work at AWS in the container team.

TL/DR. 
We do not yet support EFS integration with EKS/Fargate (this work is in progress).

Longer version. 
There may be some confusion at the root of this question. Being able to pick a Fargate platform versions only works when you consume Fargate from ECS (in which case yes, you'd need to use PV 1.4). When you consume Fargate via EKS you can't pick explicitly a Fargate pv because the way the integration works is different. Also, consider that what Fargate does in the case of EKS is "vending" Fargate tasks to be used as Kubernetes worker nodes (in other words: EKS has more to say re features supported more than Fargate has to say). You can read more about this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/the-role-of-aws-fargate-in-the-container-world/) where we tried to clarify some of these concepts. As I said, EFS and EKS/Fargate support is in the works.